# Does a picture of one's proof of automobile registration suffice to enter Mexico by car, or does have to present the physical orginal paper?

Tags: usa, paperwork, borders, automobiles, mexico

When driving from the US to Mexico, according to https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/need-passport/us-mexicoborder.html:

> Travelers should be sure to enter Mexico with valid proof of automobile registration, even if remaining in the border zone.  Entering Mexico with an expired U.S. vehicle registration may lead to the confiscation of the auto by Mexican authorities.

Does a picture of one's proof of automobile registration suffice to enter Mexico by car, or does have to present the physical orginal paper?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130672/discussion-on-question-by-franck-dernoncourt-does-a-picture-of-ones-proof-of-au).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From the comment section as well as [Reddit](https://redd.it/q9jn2q), it is recommended, and perhaps even required, to have one's original automobile registration instead of picture of it when driving in Mexico.

Note that the comment section contains some incorrect information regarding the required proof of car registration in the United States: see [Does any state or other local authorities (eg, city) in the US require to have one's original car registration in the car, or is a scan always enough?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/64546/31) for the proper information.